# How to check mysql table NULL or NOT with usage IF & ELSE in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to find out if a table is empty in the database in Laravel 5.8.

I want to use this if else statement like this, but doesn't work:

```
@foreach($accounts as $showaccounts)
@if($showaccounts->id == !NULL)
   <div class="list-item" data-id="item-11"><span class="w-40 avatar circle blue"> <img src="{{ $showaccounts->image }}" alt="."></span>
     <div class="list-body"><a href="app.message.php" class="item-title _500">{{ $showaccounts->username }}</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 @else
   <div class="no-result">
      <div class="p-4 text-center">No Results</div>
   </div>
@endif
@endforeach
```

And I tried other functions but it still didn't work.

```
@if($showaccounts->id === NULL)

@if(is_null($showaccounts->id))

@if(empty($showaccounts->id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is what you are trying to do:

```
@if($accounts->count())
  @foreach($accounts as $showaccounts)
   <div class="list-item" data-id="item-11"><span class="w-40 avatar circle blue"> <img src="{{ $showaccounts->image }}" alt="."></span>
     <div class="list-body"><a href="app.message.php" class="item-title _500">{{ $showaccounts->username }}</a>
     </div>
   </div> 
  @endforeach
@else
  <div class="no-result">
    <div class="p-4 text-center">No Results</div>
  </div>
@endif
```

But it would be better if you would construct this like below:

```
@forelse($accounts as $account)
  <div class="list-item" data-id="item-11"><span class="w-40 avatar circle blue"> <img src="{{ $account->image }}" alt="."></span>
    <div class="list-body">
      <a href="app.message.php" class="item-title _500">{{ $account->username }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
@empty
  <div class="no-result">
    <div class="p-4 text-center">No Results</div>
  </div>
@endforelse
```

Loop variables usually take the plural-singular form, example: accounts-account.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you checked element property. but you wanted to check table. so, you can just try to get count of element collection

```
@if( $showaccounts->count() )
    @foreach($accounts as $showaccounts)
        <div class="list-item" data-id="item-11"><span class="w-40 avatar circle blue"> <img src="{{ $showaccounts->image }}" alt="."></span>
            <div class="list-body"><a href="app.message.php" class="item-title _500">{{ $showaccounts->username }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <div class="no-result">
        <div class="p-4 text-center">No Results</div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: This function did not work unfortunately. If db table have rows, data is written to the screen that's okay.. but if db table is empty, else is not activated and no written "No Results".

Comment: then add to your post following info: how you getting your $showaccounts and what you see in dump of this variable

Answer (score 0):

Use isset https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php 
or you can use isEmpty() on collections in laravel.

So in your case @if(isset($accounts )) { 
    what this do, is if variable is set do what u need 
}

or($accounts->isEmpty())
isEmpty checks if collection is empty

Hope it helps.

Comment: This function did not work unfortunately. If db table have rows, data is written to the screen that's okay.. but if db table is empty, else is not activated and no written "No Results".

Comment: Lets say u have $data = Account::get();
*@if($data->isEmpty())
 No data
*@else
 do what u need with data
*@endif

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@forelse ($accounts as $showaccounts)
<div class="list-item" data-id="item-11"><span class="w-40 avatar circle 
 blue"> <img src="{{ $showaccounts->image }}" alt="."></span>
 <div class="list-body"><a href="app.message.php" class="item-title _500">{{ 
 $showaccounts->username }}</a>
 </div>
 </div>
@empty
<div class="no-result">
    <div class="p-4 text-center">No Results</div>
</div>
@endforelse
```